# Enthalpy of fusion - water

Tags: thermodynamics, water, fusion

Trying to solve:

$$l = \frac{Q(\text{melt})}{m(\text{ice})}$$

$$Q(\text{melting  of   water}) = Q(\text{heating  of 
 ice}) - Q(\text{cooling  of  water})$$

$$l \times m(\text{ice}) = c \times m(\text{water}) \times \Delta T - c \times m(\text{water}) \times \Delta T$$

Temperatures:

ice temp = $0^{\circ} C$

water temp = $68.0^{\circ} C$

stable temp = $7.8^{\circ} C$

It's not accurate and does not have to be.

I can't figure out those two $\Delta T$. Can someone explain it to me?

What is the change in temperature? I figured first $\Delta T$ is $7.8^{\circ} C$ and second is $61.2^{\circ} C$, but it gives a negative answer and I can't find any information.

English is not my native language, so sorry if I don't find the right words for something.

Okay i got The result right. Delta T for melt is 7.8 q(cool) is 61.2

Comment: What is the exact problem statement?

Comment: Have you tried here: @ https://www.savemyexams.co.uk/a-level/physics/ocr/17/revision-notes/5-newtonian-world--astrophysics/5-1-thermal-properties-of-materials/5-1-6-specific-heat-capacity/  and @ https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zcncjty/revision/4  ?

Comment: Also here: @ https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zcpwrwx/revision/4